# Cannot connect to docker daemon on powershell

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am currently on Docker Desktop (Windows11 PC) and running container over alpine.

```
  docker build /DIRECTORY/
```

above command spits following error

```
     Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Help me figure out - using PowerShell (Terminal) Window.

Comment: first check whether `Docker` is running?! If it is running then there might be also other issues like: `Docker Socket` or `Docker Client Permission`. First let's check the Docker status, then let us know if issue still exists

Comment: I tested docker running or not by explicitly typing    `docker run hello-world`. The result works out just fine. The problem still persists.

Comment: particularly what `image` or `Dockerfile` are you trying to run? And what is your reason to use `Powershell`? In my case, I mostly use `Gitbash`, cos UI is very friendly.

Comment: I find 'Powershell' easy to use. 'Dockerfile' is for pre-build RL agent.

Comment: can u share ur docker file inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your docker is not running.

You can check the docker logs from:  AppData\Local\Docker\log\vm\dockerd.log

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/logs/

You need to start Docker to access Docker-related services.

```
Restart-Service docker
```

Once Docker daemon is running then you can issue your commands.

Reference: https://linuxhint.com/resolve-docker-daemon-not-running/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested docker running or not by explicitly typing    `docker run hello-world`. The result works out just fine. The problem still persists.